# Access contacts folder outlook vb.net

Tags: vb.net, outlook, contacts

I want to access all the contacts from the global adress list found in outlook at current I can only access the "Contacts" folder ussing the following code...

```
 Dim cContacts As Outlook.MAPIFolder = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts)
                Dim oItems As Outlook.Items = cContacts.Items
```

How can I achive / access this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Namespace.AddressLists` for that. E.g. `Application.Session.AddressLists.Item("All users")`